# Html table not formatting as expected?

Tags: html

I am having some format issue with a table I am working on.  See screenshot snap of table row below:

[image]

Below is the html for my table - so the problem is if I do an F12 and highlight the * column it is showing as taking up alot of space and not just 5px which I have specified - which then pushes the validation messages up and doesnt lok nice when there is space they could be filling.  Is there something silly I am missing?

```
<table class="ui-widget-content" style="width: 565px; height: 200px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10px;"></td>
        <td class="label">Forename :
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Forename, new { id = "foreName", style = "width:150px" })
        </td>
        <td style="width:5px;">*</td>
        <td class="field-validation-error" style="width: 180px;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Forename)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10px;"></td>
        <td id="FloorText" class="label">Surname :
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname, new { style = "width:150px" })
        </td>
         <td style="width:5px;">*</td>
        <td class="field-validation-error" style="width: 180px;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10px;"></td>
        <td class="label">Email Address :
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { style = "width:150px" })
        </td>
         <td style="width:5px;">*</td>
        <td class="field-validation-error" style="width: 180px;">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit - Question edited to show screenshot of code in F12 - it seems to be the span that is auto generated - how can I add a width to this?**

[image]

Comment: Can you give the final html output ?

Comment: JsFiddle this please. Try removing the table width declaration

Comment: is there any live sample ?

Comment: Question edited to include F12 of what is seen - can really do a JS Fiddle as it is using Fields from my Model on screen so mocked up in JS Fiddle would not be correct.